# Why is my bootstrap tab not displayed when the page loads?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tabs

I am writing to you because I used the bootstrap tabs, but I have a problem. The tabs work well on click, each click leads to the desired content. The problem is that when the page loads, the content is empty. I have to click to display some content, whereas normally the first tab should appear by default (I believe this is done thanks to aria-selected = "true")

Can you tell me why it is not displayed by default please? Thank you very much !

Here is the link to the documentation of the bootstrap tabs :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#tabs

**My HTML code :**

```
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                          <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#reservation" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Ma réservation en détail</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                          <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#imprimer" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Imprimer mes documents de voyage</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                          <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#payer" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Payer le solde de mon séjour</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="reservation" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="imprimer" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="payer" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Comment: I just replicated your code in this [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y78tdwur/1/) and all seem to be working fine. Have you written any other styles aside from using Bootstrap?

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt! Indeed I have a whole code around. At least thanks to you I know it's because of my CSS I'm going to explore this track thank you!

Comment: I deleted all my css and it doesn't work. So it must come from my html structure. I keep looking ;) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to those who helped me. I finally found out where the problem came from. I have the latest version of Bootstrap installed on my website (Bootrstrap 5), and the documentation works with Bootstrap 3 ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed class tab-content

```
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sameera. Indeed I forgot to put it in my post sorry ... but it is present. I have tried everything I do not understand the problem. But I don't think you can help me ... It must come from somewhere else on my website.

Comment: I believe I found the problem. My website use the latest version of Bootstrap while the tutorial is on Bootstrap 3 ... Thanks again